# I don't see the results of my Logstash filter in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-grok, filebeat

I have setup successfully my system for centralized logging using: elasticsearch-logstash-filebeat-kibana.

I cant see logs using the filebeat template index in Kibana. The problems arrives when I try to create a logstash filter in order to parse my log files properly.

I'm using grok patterns, so first one I created this pattern (/opt/logstash/patterns/grok-paterns):

```
CUSTOMLOG %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} - %{USER:auth} - %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} - \[%{DATA:pyid}\]\[%{DATA:source}\]\[%{DATA:searchId}\] - %{GREEDYDATA:logmessage}
```

And this is the logstash filter (/etc/logstash/conf.d/11-log-filter.conf):

```
filter {
  if [type] == "log" {
    grok {
       match => { "message" => "%{CUSTOMLOG}" }
       patterns_dir => "/opt/logstash/patterns"
    }
    mutate {
       rename => [ "logmessage", "message" ]
    }

    date {
        timezone => "Europe/London"
        locale => "en"
        match => [ "timestamp" , "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS" ]
    }
 }}
```

Apparently the parser is working fine when I test it from command line:

```
[root@XXXXX logstash]# bin/logstash -f test.conf 
Settings: Default pipeline workers: 4
Logstash startup completed

2016-06-03 12:55:57,718 - root - INFO - [27232][service][751282714902528] - here goes my message

{
   "message" => "here goes my message",
  "@version" => "1",
"@timestamp" => "2016-06-03T11:55:57.718Z",
      "host" => "19598",
 "timestamp" => "2016-06-03 12:55:57,718",
      "auth" => "root",
  "loglevel" => "INFO",
      "pyid" => "27232",
    "source" => "service",
  "searchId" => "751282714902528"
 }
```

However... log do not appear in Kibana, I don't even see "_grokparsefailure" tasgs, so I guest that the parser is working but I can find logs.

What am I doing wrong? Do I forget something?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

Input (02-beats-input.conf):

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
    ssl => true
    ssl_certificate => "/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt"
    ssl_key => "/etc/pki/tls/private/logstash-forwarder.key"
  }
}
```

Output (30-elasticsearch-output.conf):

```
output {
 elasticsearch {
   hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
   sniffing => true
   manage_template => false
   index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
   document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your input and output as well?

Comment: Edited and added input and output

Comment: If you use Filebeat to send data to Logstash, then you will end up using the Logstash template (`logstash-*`) rather than the Filebeat one.

Comment: But you are setting the `index` in the ES output in your update (I didn't notice when I typed it), so that is suspect. One trick for debugging Logstash is to add `stdout { }` as an extra output. If it never prints anything, then you're not actually getting output.

Comment: Actually I cant see anything using the logstash-* index

Comment: @Curro Do you see any documents if you add `stdout { codec => rubydebug }` to the output list (put it before ES to see if any output is happening and after ES to see if it's actually getting past ES)?

Comment: Well guys! is working fine now.... actually It was working from the beginning! It was a problem with dates, I have servers in diferent timezones and when I was parsing the date and setting a common timezone I was storing datetimes for the future (i.e: 15:10 right now and log is being stored with time 18:10). So I didn't see logs when I was filtering for last 15 min, last X hours.... I only can see them filtering for whole day.
Yeah! I know.... stupid mistake.

Comment: Thanks for your help! ;)